# htmlagilitypack c# - input form, wait, and load output generated on server

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I just have one simple question, before I put hours of work in this and finding out it can't be done:

By HTML-agility pack (selenium and stuff isn't working for me) I want to input some text on this userform:

https://wordsmith.org/anagram/animation.html

then click the button, wait till gif is generated, and then download gif.

Is this possible or should I look for other solution? Sadly enough I'm not allowed to input other browser on my work-computer (the one i'm building the code on) so selenium and stuff isn't working for me.

Comment: 1) You don't need to type that input. It's a post request to https://wordsmith.org/anagram/animation.cgi and some form-data. And the 2. that animation is not a gif it's a canvas and I don't think HtmlAgilityPack can convert a canvas to a gif.

Comment: @Eldar thanks for first part of answer. about gif: you're right, this is option that can be chosen under "advanced", should have posted: https://wordsmith.org/anagram/animation-advanced.html then a gif can be generated. is downloading this gif (like right click -> save image as) possible?

Comment: Ah then yes it's definitely possible all you need is to set `gifanimation=1` in your post request. And the gif image is base64 format you need to get the src attribute of the element and save it as binary.

Comment: Thanks!! Nice to hear, I'm gonna work on this tonight!